# System.NotSupportedException: 'The given path's format is not supported.'

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, connection-string

```
string dbPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
dbPath = Path.Combine(dbPath, "Database1.mdf");
cn = new SqlConnection (@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory| "+dbPath+";Integrated Security=True");
GetAllRecords();
```

When I run this code, it displays this error

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The given path's format is not supported.'

I want to connect the database located in current user's document folder. How to fix this?

Comment: It would help if you knew what database you were using. You have tagged this question MySQL but you're clearly using SQL Server. Also, the SQL tag is inappropriate because this question has nothing to do with SQL, which is the language you use to query a database.

Comment: This question also has nothing to do with WinForms. Look at the code. Would anything be different in a Console app? Nope, so not a WinForms question. I have edited the tags to make then more appropriate to the question.

Comment: It's a small thing but I would recommend using string interpolation wherever you need to insert substrings like this. Code starts to get hard to read the more concatenation operators you have. As a rule, I rarely use more than one and sometimes not even that. `cn = new SqlConnection ($@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename={dbPath};Integrated Security=True");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AttachDbFilename` attribute of the connection string has to actually contain the path to the file. Yours obviously does not. At run time, `|DataDirectory|` gets replaced with the path of the data directory, which will likely be the folder from which your executable was run. If your data file is in your documents folder then it's obviously not under the program folder, so why are you using `|DataDirectory|` at all? Get rid of that and use the path of the data file.

The point of `|DataDirectory|` is that you can put your data file in your program folder and hard-code the path, even though you won't actually know the path of that folder until run time. If you're not storing your data file in the data directory then don't use `|DataDirectory|` in the connection string. That is most useful when you have a source data file in your project folder that is automatically copied to your output folder when you build. `|DataDirectory|` will then work while debugging and after release, no matter where the application is.

Answer (score 0):

I think it just needs to be `new SqlConnection ($"...AttachDbFilename={dbPath}");` without the `DataDirectory`.